# mpiexec was unable to launch the specified application (Raspberry pi)

Tags: mpi, raspberry-pi, mpiexec

I get the same error for each of the 3 following commands.   is my ip address from ifconfig.  Any ideas on what is going wrong?  It worked fine last night.

```
mpiexec -f machinefile -n <number> hostname
mpiexec -f machinefile –n 1 hostname
mpiexec -f machinefile -n 2 ~/mpich_build/examples/cpi
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
mpiexec was unable to launch the specified application as it could not find an executable:

Executable: -f
Node: raspberrypi

while attempting to start process rank 0.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I'm following the tutorial from http://www.southampton.ac.uk/~sjc/raspberrypi/pi_supercomputer_southampton.htm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess is that you've installed OpenMPI, as vs MPICH2 as given in the examples, yes?  There's nothing wrong with that, but the options for things like specifying machine files are somewhat different.   You'll want

```
mpiexec -machinefile machinefile -n 1 hostname
```

etc.

Comment: Works almost perfectly.  I am somewhat confused as to why -f was working before and stopped working though.  One issue:  repeats 'Process 0 of 1 is on raspberrypi' no matter the number of processes.  Should that concern me?

Comment: That suggests that you (a) originally had only mpich2 in your path, which you compiled and ran the programs with and then (b) either installed OpenMPI, or your path changed so that openmpi came first in your path.  All processes thinking they are 0 of 1 typically results in compiling/linking against one MPI implementation and running with the mpiexec of another, which won't work.  For now, I'd suggest completely uninstalling one (say, OpenMPI), and get things working with just mpich2.   Recompile all your sample programs to be sure and try again.