# OpenMPI Execution Problems on Raspberry Pi

Tags: c, raspberry-pi, cluster-computing, openmpi

I am trying to build a beowulf cluster with Raspberry Pi. I downloaded the following packages of OpenMPI: openmpi-bin, openmpi-common, libopenmpi1.3, libopenmpi-dbg, libopenmpi-dev. I used static IP on each of the Raspberrys and tested the connection between each of them and it was working. I also enabled the ssh and I used it to login from one Raspberry to all the other Raspberrys.

This is the following code I used:

```
#include <mpi.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 int tid,nthreads;
 char *cpu_name;

  /* add in MPI startup routines */
  /* 1st: launch the MPI processes on each node */
  MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);

  /* 2nd: request a thread id, sometimes called a "rank" from
          the MPI master process, which has rank or tid == 0
   */
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &tid);

  /* 3rd: this is often useful, get the number of threads
          or processes launched by MPI, this should be NCPUs-1
   */
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &nthreads);

  /* on EVERY process, allocate space for the machine name */
  cpu_name    = (char *)calloc(80,sizeof(char));

  /* get the machine name of this particular host ... well
     at least the first 80 characters of it ... */
  gethostname(cpu_name,80);

  printf("hello MPI user: from process = %i on machine=%s, of NCPU=%i processes\n",
         tid, cpu_name, nthreads);
  MPI_Finalize();
  return(0);
}
```

I tested the code first with only 2 boards and it worked fine no problems no errors and it printed the printf statement in the code.
I created a host file which includes the following:

```
Pi0
Pi1
Pi2
Pi3
```

I have 4 Raspberry Pis. I copied the code on each of them and compiled the code also using the following statements:

```
mpicc -g -0O -c hello-mpi.c -o hello-mpi.o
mpicc -g hello-mpi.o -o hello-mpi
```

I executed the code with the following statement:

```
mpirun -np 4 -hostfile hostfile hello-mpi
```

when I run the program nothing happens it just gives me an new empty line. No errors are given also. Any suggestion what I can I do to make it work

Comment: for OpenMPI use (-n) parameter instead of (-np) : http://stackoverflow.com/a/13898537/992406

Comment: You could try using the mpirun `-output-filename` option to redirect the output to files. I would also flush stdout right after the `printf` using `fflush(stdout);` because I'm paranoid.

Comment: Do you have passwordless ssh access from one Pi to the others?

Comment: Hello, the problem was with the ssh password, I made passwordless ssh access and the program worked fine and it showed the output